# Serilog not working in ASP.NET Core 7 Integration Test with CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, .net-6.0, serilog

I'm trying to use separate configuration file for `Serilog` in my `Integration Tests` in my `ASP.NET Core 7 Web API`.

Here is my `Program.cs`,

```cs
//Read Configuration from appSettings
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
//Initialize Logger
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .CreateLogger();

Log.Information($"Starting {typeof(Program).Assembly.FullName}");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Host.UseSerilog();//Uses Serilog instead of default .NET Logger

// Removed code for brevity

var app = builder.Build();

// Removed code for brevity

await app.RunAsync();
```

Here is my `CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>`,

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var projectDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
        {
            conf.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(projectDir, "appsettings.Test.json"));
        });

        builder.UseEnvironment("Test");

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(async services =>
        {
            // Removed code for brevity
        });
    }
}
```

As seen in the above code, I have my `appsettings.Test.json` inside the root of my `Integration Test` project.

When I run the test, it always takes the `appsettings.json` from my `API` project. So I tried to change my `Program.cs` as follows,

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

if (builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("Test"))
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json")
    .Build();
    //Initialize Logger
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                .CreateLogger();
}
else 
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .Build();
    //Initialize Logger
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                .CreateLogger();
}

Log.Information($"Starting {typeof(Program).Assembly.FullName}");

builder.Host.UseSerilog();//Uses Serilog instead of default .NET Logger

// Removed code for brevity

var app = builder.Build();

// Removed code for brevity

await app.RunAsync();
```

After the above change no logs we recorded during my `Integration Test`. So I decided to add `appsettings.Test.json` to my `API` project and `Copy Always` to output directory but still no luck.

Previously when I was using `Startup.cs`, I used to override `CreateHost` inside `CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>` as shown below,

```cs
protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    //Read Configuration from appSettings
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json")
        .Build();
    //Initialize Logger
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
        .CreateLogger();

    Log.Information($"Starting Integration Tests.");

    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                        .UseSerilog()
                        .ConfigureWebHost(x =>
                        {
                            x.UseStartup<Startup>();
                            x.UseTestServer();
                        });
    return builder;
}
```

But now after moving to new way in `ASP.NET Core 7`. There is no `Startup.cs` and the test was giving error like,

> No Application was selected to run/start.

So I removed `override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()` from `CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>`.

Please can anyone assist on how to use separate configuration file for `Integration Test` in `ASP.NET Core 7`?

Comment: You could keep startup class as in .net 5,also you could check this document about Test with WebApplicationFactory or TestServer in .net 6/7, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#test-with-webapplicationfactory-or-testserver

Comment: What type do you pass in `CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>` as I assume that `TProgram` is a type parameter? Can you show a derived factory? And how (or did) you overcome the `Program.cs` accessibility problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, as net7 microsoft docs (and Visual Studio 2022 intellisense/warnings) on changing the appSettings config are not aligned with what Serilog requires.

Microsoft's recommendation to change appSettings config (and then setup Serilog, based on Serilog's recommendations):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear();
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("siteid.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
if (args != null) builder.Configuration.AddCommandLine(args);

// Configure Serilog
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
          loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
);
```

But this results in Serilog not logging anything as you stated.

My solution was to config appSettings using `builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration()`, as `builder.Host` is what Serilog seems to use:

```
#pragma warning disable ASP0013 // Warning suggests switching from using Configure methods to WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
    config.Sources.Clear();
    config.AddJsonFile("siteid.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    if (args != null) config.AddCommandLine(args);
});
#pragma warning restore ASP0013 

// Configure Serilog
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
          loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
);
```

This works and the correct appSettings are populated and Serilog logs as expected. However Visual Studio shows a Warning and suggests switching from using Configure methods (ConfigureAppConfiguration) to WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration (builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile), thus the `#pragma warning disable ASP0013` lines.

So in your specific case, I can't offer any guidance in regards to your factory, but on updating your Program.cs, I might suggest this as a soution:

```
#pragma warning disable ASP0013 // Warning suggests switching from using Configure methods to WebApplicationBuilder.Configuration
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment; // getting enviroment here instead of your `builder.Environment.IsEnvironment("Test")`
    config.Sources.Clear();  // If you want to clear existing defaults ???
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);  //(e.g. appsettings.Test.json) overrides any values in appsettings.json
    //config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    //if (args != null) config.AddCommandLine(args);
});
#pragma warning restore ASP0013 

// Configure Serilog
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
          loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
);
```